# Configuring an Elastic Beanstalk environment's Load Balancer for TCP Passthrough in a custom VPC with config files (.ebextensions)

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-vpc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I've attempted to follow this particular document

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-tcp-passthrough.html

With no luck for my particular needs.  What is required was a Layer 4 TCP passthrough from our proxy server through the ELB that does not terminate SSL until the Tomcat backend.  The ingress port is TCP 443, egress is 8443.  It is also necessary to utilize a custom VPC rather than the default.  How can this be accomplished utilizing configuration files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve  with the following config files:

https-instance-balancer.config

```
    {
        "Resources": {
            "AWSEBSecurityGroup": {
                "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
                "Properties": {
                    "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxxxx",
                    "GroupDescription": "EC28443Ingress",
                    "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                        {
                            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                            "FromPort": 8443,
                            "ToPort": 8443,
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup": {
                "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
                "Properties": {
                    "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxxxx",
                    "GroupDescription": "ELB443and8443Ingress",
                    "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                        {
                            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                            "FromPort": 443,
                            "ToPort": 443,
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SecurityGroupEgress": [
                        {
                            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                            "FromPort": 8443,
                            "ToPort": 8443,
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "AWSEBLoadBalancer": {
                "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
                "Properties": {
                    "Listeners": [
                        {
                            "LoadBalancerPort": 443,
                            "Protocol": "TCP",
                            "InstancePort": 8443,
                            "InstanceProtocol": "TCP"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup",
                                "GroupId"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

https-lb-passthrough.config

```
    {
      "option_settings": {
        "aws:elb:listener:443": {
          "ListenerProtocol": "TCP",
          "InstancePort": 8443,
          "InstanceProtocol": "TCP"
        },
        "aws:elb:healthcheck": {
          "Target": "TCP:8443"
        }
      }
    }
```

This could probably be accomplished more easily with software such as Terraform, but that may not be an option for some.

Comment: You would think that A) this is a common use case and B) the documentation provided by AWS would include such an example. I've been banging my head all day trying to get their examples to work with Play as it is not launched as root and therefor can get access to the default ports - ergo had to do precisely the above -- used your files virtually as is and worked instantly! Thank you.

Comment: Damn it! Scratch that  - turns out I accidentally connected to the ec2 instance and not the front end load balancer. Seems like you've made the instance serve on port 443 somehow (which might be useful if I can get the ELB to talk to it - completely unsure how the certificate is served (correctly I might add) however is it IS picking that up somehow) ... Back to the head banging...